# Do you have a legal right to stop a card payment by email?

Tags: united-kingdom, payment, credit-card

[According to Citizens Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/debt-and-money/banking/stopping-a-future-payment-on-your-debit-or-credit-card) it is the law that you can stop a card payment.  They also say you can do this by email.  It is not completely clear if you can put these two statements together and get that it is the law that you can stop a card payment by email:

> The law says you can withdraw your consent and stop a future payment under a continuous payment authority at any time up to the end of business on the day before the payment is due.
>
> To withdraw consent, simply tell whoever issued your card (the bank, building society or credit card company) that you don’t want the payment to be made. You can tell the card issuer by phone, email or letter.

Is it actually the law that you can do this by email?  If so, practically how do you do this?  [From a sample of one](https://www.santander.co.uk/personal/support/customer-support/future-dated-card-payments), banks do not obviously provide an email address for this, and they are frequently not set up for validation by email.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is legal for you to send your bank an email, **or** whether the bank is required by law to provide you with an email address, and to act upon your request within the same working day that you notify them? Because those are distinctly different things.

Comment: @MichaelHall I guess I mean that law the the CI is referring to, does it give one the right to provide this data by email and it to be acted upon.  Read one way it is being very specific about the law, read the other way it is synonymous with "however the bank tells you to communicate the information".  I wonder what is the correct interpretation of the law.

Comment: FWIW, the way I read it is "however the bank tells you to communicate the information"...

Comment: I've been going around and around fca.org.uk and I can't find this right explained anywhere. I found stuff about getting refunds for unwanted or fraudulent payments, but nothing about stopping future payments.